# angularjs defining values with different functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this small issue where I am calling a service method in one function, and then trying to use the values from that function in another function (Both functions are in the same controller).

But when calling the values it says they are undefined.

the bottom coding is basically what I want to achieve not my real coding.

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope)
{
     $scope.a = function()            // a function calling service data
     {
       $scope.value1 = array[];       //array[] list of all data called
       console.log(value[0].item1);   // value is defined
     }

     $scope.b = funtion(value1)
     {
       console.log(value1[0].item1);  // returns undefined
     }
)};
```

As shown in **function a** the value is defined but not in **function b** how do I keep the same value of **item1** when calling it from another function?

Comment: Where have you defined `value` ?

Comment: don't I define it with `$scope.value1 = array[];` @RayonDabre

Comment: then you should use `$scope.value1` not just `value1` in your `console.log`

Comment: the code you have posted already has some mistakes, like value is not defined, you are defining `value1` then using `value`. Also show us how you are calling the function `b`, if you dont pass the array as parameter it will say undefined

Comment: `value` seems a global variable whereas `value1` is a `scope` variable..

Comment: I see using scope works how do I 'globalize' value than? @RayonDabre

Comment: `$scope` variables are `global` inside controller `context`..

Comment: ok thanks will use $scope then! mind posting an answer in order to accept it? @RayonDabre

Comment: Are you invoking `b()` anywhere ?

Comment: yes in my html with a click event? @RayonDabre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do  $scope.value[0].item1
since the array value is in the $scope